# How does MediaFoundation set the brightness and other properties of UVC cameras

Tags: directshow, ms-media-foundation

I am currently using the MediaFoundation API to preview UVC cameras. How can I set/get the brightness, contrast, and other properties of the camera? Although it can be implemented using the IAMVideoProcAmp interface, it is still a DirectShow interface.

Comment: It's not a problem if it's a direct show interface, although direct show is" "legacy" , it's not going anywhere, so if it works you can use it, or if you really want everything more modern, you should use WinRT (that mostly wraps Media Foundation) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for your reply and suggestions, I think I should continue to use the DirectShow interface to implement my project, as I haven't learned how to use WinRT yet. Thank you again.